# Export files from git revision with Process()

Tags: swift, git, process, swift3, arguments

To export git revision I use the command:

```
    git archive master | tar -x -C /Users/me/Desktop/export/
```

which works fine in terminal.

Using this with Process()

```
    let task = Process()
    task.currentDirectoryPath = "/Users/me/Documents/Project/HelpMe/"
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/git"
    task.arguments = ["archive", "master", "|", "tar", "-x", "-C", "/Users/me/Desktop/export/"]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

returns an error

> Error: unknown switch `x\'\nusage: git archive []  [...]\n   or: git archive --list\n   or: git archive --remote  [--exec ] []  [...]\n   or: git archive --remote  [--exec ] --list\n\n    --format         archive format\n    --prefix      prepend prefix to each pathname in the archive\n    -o, --output    write the archive to this file\n    --worktree-attributes\n                          read .gitattributes in working directory\n    -v, --verbose         report archived files on stderr\n    -0                    store only\n    -1                    compress faster\n    -9                    compress better\n\n    -l, --list            list supported archive formats\n\n    --remote        retrieve the archive from remote repository \n    --exec       path to the remote git-upload-archive command

Using one argument

```
    task.arguments = ["archive master | tar -x -C /Users/me/Desktop/export/"]
```

returns the error

> git: \'archive master | tar -x -C /Users/me/Desktop/export/\' is not a git command. See \'git --help\'.

The problem is the `|` character. `Process()` launches all arguments with single quotes

```
git 'archive' 'master' '|' 'tar' '-x' '-C' '/Users/me/Desktop/export/'
```

If I use this in a terminal and remove the single quotes around `|` everything is working fine.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try to put all arguments in one string `"archive master | tar -x -C /Users/me/Desktop/export/"`.

Comment: Using the string as one argument doesn't work neither (description above).

Comment: Try to replace `Process()` with `Task()`. Can not test in the moment. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: Swift Compiler Error: 'NSTask' has been renamed to 'Process'

Comment: I think i need `Pipe` to redirect the output of one process into the input of another process. First `Process.arguments = ["archive", "master]`, second `Process.arguments = ["-x", "-C", "/Users/me/Desktop/export/"]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Cocoa Class `ExportGit`
2. Create a Objective-C Bridging Header and include `#import "ExportGit.h"`
3. Create a method

`- (void)exportGit {
    system("cd /Users/me/Documents/Projekte/HelpMe && git archive master | tar -x -C /Users/me/Desktop/export/");
}`

4. Call Objective-C from Swift code

`let exportGit = ExportGit()
 exportGit.exportgit();`

Resume: It should work with Swift `Process()` and `standardOutput` / `standardInput` but after a few days trying i use `system()` now which took me 3 minutes to make it work.